# Random number generation without using bit operations

Tags: math, graphics, random

I'm writing a vertex shader at the moment, and I need some random numbers. Vertex shader hardware doesn't have logical/bit operations, so I cannot implement any of the standard random number generators.
Is it possible to make a random number generator using only standard arithmetic? the randomness doesn't have to be particularly good!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't mind crappy randomness, a classic method is

```
x[n+1] = (x[n] * x[n] + C) mod N
```

where C and N are constants, C != 0 and C != -2, and N is prime. This is a typical pseudorandom generator for Pollard Rho factoring. Try C = 1 and N = 8051, those work ok.

Comment: Sure. You don't need great statistical quality for graphics.

Answer (score 2):

Vertex shaders sometimes have built-in noise generators for you to use, such as cg's `noise()` function.

Comment: HLSL does have a noise function which I could use:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb509629(VS.85).aspx

However whenever I have used it in the past it's never worked, in fact until recently I believe it was marked as "not implemented yet"!

Answer (score 2):

Use a [linear congruential generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator):

```
X_(n+1) = (a * X_n + c) mod m
```

Those aren't that strong, but at least they are well known and can have long periods. The Wikipedia page also has good recommendations:

> The period of a general LCG is at most
>   m, and for some choices of a much less
>   than that. The LCG will have a full
>   period if and only if:
>
> ```
> 1. c and m are relatively prime,
> 2. a - 1 is divisible by all prime factors of m,
> 3. a - 1 is a multiple of 4 if m is a multiple of 4
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Believe it or not, I used newx = oldx * 5 + 1 (or a slight variation of it) in several videogames. The randomness is horrible--it's more of a scrambled sequence than a random generator. But sometimes that's all you need. If I recall correctly, it goes through all numbers before it repeats.

It has some terrible characteristics. It doesn't ever give you the same number twice in a row.  A few of us did a bunch of tests on variations of it and we used some variations in other games.

We used it when there was no good modulo available to us. It's just a shift by two and two adds (or a multiply by 5 and one add). I would never use it nowadays for random numbers--I'd use an LCG--but maybe it would work OK for a shader where speed is crucial and your instruction set may be limited.

Comment: hehe, that's an interesting RNG, the most mathematically easy to understand I've seen for sure!
I'll have a play with this, since as you say speed is crucial.